# How can I fit a div to its content and align it to the right?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a simple chat application and can't seem to display the chat text belonging to one user stick to the left while the other user's message sticks to the right.

Here is a sample of the code:

```css
.chat-session {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  padding: 1%;
}

.user1 {
  padding: 0 2px 2px 2px;
  border: 1px solid #09aedc4f;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #09aedc4f;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.user2 {
  padding: 0 2px 2px 2px;
  text-align: right;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.493);
  background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.493);
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-session">
    <div class="user1">Hello</div>
    <div class="user2">Hi</div>
    <div class="user1">What's up?</div>
    <div class="user2">Not much</div>
</div>
```

I would like the divs to fit the text size and user2's div to align right. I have tried `display: inline-block;` to fit the divs, but that just displays them all on the same line. I have also tried `float: right;` and `float: left;` but that also displays them on the same line.

Can someone help?

Comment: display:table + margin-left:auto to push the ones to the right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `display` with the table-layout algorithm to shrink element to its content, then  `max-width` and `margin-left:auto`

```css
.chat-session {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  padding: 1%;
}

.chat-session>* {/* Update */
  display: table;/* for infos : okay with any browser for ages and only from IE8 for MSIE */
  max-width: 100%;
}

.user1 {
  padding: 0 2px 2px 2px;
  border: 1px solid #09aedc4f;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #09aedc4f;
  margin-bottom: 2px; 
}

.user2 {
  padding: 0 2px 2px 2px;
  text-align: right;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.493);
  background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.493);
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-left: auto/* Update */
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-session">
  <div class="user1">Hello</div>
  <div class="user2">Hi</div>
  <div class="user1">What's up?</div>
  <div class="user2">Not much</div>
  <div class="user1">What's up? What's up? What's up? What's up? What's up if there a long text here?</div>
  <div class="user2">Not much</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man, that solved it!

Answer (score 2):

Your can put your message tag in another tag with `text-align` property

```css
.chat-session {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  padding: 1%;
}

.user1 {
  display:inline;
  padding: 0 2px 2px 2px;
  border: 1px solid #09aedc4f;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #09aedc4f;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.user2 {
  display:inline;
  padding: 0 2px 2px 2px;

  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.493);
  background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.493);
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.message-right{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
}

.message-left{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-session">
    <div class="message-left"><div class="user1">Hello</div></div>
    <div class="message-right"><div class="user2">Hi</div></div>
    <div class="message-left"><div class="user1">What's up?</div></div>
    <div class="message-right"><div class="user2">Not much</div></div>
</div>
```